# How to display list of tags of a given branch in CVS?

Tags: tags, branch, cvs

Anyone knows how to display tags of a given branch in CVS? 
Or is there any script to do the parsing of log file for this purpose?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CVS has the ability to give you a list of tags associated with a branch.

You could try something like the following:

```
cvs history -T | grep <yourbranch>
```

Though I have found `cvs history` to be a little flaky. eg. not showing me tags that I know exist.